# Help with Calculated Column Formula on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I have a SharePoint List that I need to build a calculated column for but am having issues trying to put together the formula.

For the purpose of this forum, the columns needed in the formula are "Date1", "Date2", "Column1" & "Column2". The calculated column is called Status and I want it to return 'Red', 'Amber' or 'Green'.

The criteria is below:

**Red**
Date1 is more than 365 days ago from today

**Amber**
Date2 is less than 90 days away from today

**Green**
Column1 = Yes AND Column2 = Yes AND (Date1 is less than 365 ago from today OR Date2 is more than 90 days away from today)

Answer (score 0):

Is the color you need the color of this column value or the background color? Or just want to return the color of the word itself? If it is the former, it is recommended that you use column formatting to achieve it.
Reference：

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#apply-formatting-based-on-date-ranges